# Redirect with arguments and message

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

I want to do a redirect with arguments and at the same time send a message to the redirected page.

Where to redirect:

```
path('companies/<int:pk>/', AccountCompanyDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_company')


from django.shortcuts import redirect

def post_view(request, id):
    return redirect('detail_company', pk=id)
```

I want to send to the page to which will be redirected a 'message' to show to the user why it was redirected.

It is possible?

Comment: Your redirect looks fine. You can use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) to create the message.

Comment: @Alasdair, the issue is not the redirect as it is, but I don't know how at the same time with the redirect send a message back; I saw some example of using message framework, but not with redirect

Comment: The messages framework works whether you return a regular http response or a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution is to modify your urls.py in this way:

```
  url(r'^'desired_url_to_redirect/(?:(?P<error_key>[0-9]+)/)?$', views.'name_of_your_view', name='name_of_your_view'),
```

The second parameter is optional and would act as a key for the type error. The only thing left would be to update your template to present the desired message based on the type of error.

For defining your view don't forget to insert as a second parameter 'error_key=None'

Comment: I'm using Django 2.0 the new url pattern, so this is not a solution